# Exception occuring while login in C#

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, exception

I am using windows application and WCF service in my application. I have published my service in web server and also i referred that endPointAddress in my config settings. The application working properly in my system and some systems but it could not be login in another system. And its throws an exception while login...

Here i mentioned my exception, can any one tell me the solution of this problem?
Thanks in Advance..

Exception:

> SOAP security negotiation with 'http://example.com/DashBoardPointsService/Service.svc' for target 'http://example.com/DashBoardPointsService/Service.svc' failed. See inner exception for more details.

Inner Exception:

> System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception: The Security Support Provider Interface (SSPI) negotiation failed.
>      at System.ServiceModel.Security.WindowsSspiNegotiation.GetOutgoingBlob(Byte[] incomingBlob, IExtendedProtectionSupport extendedProtectionSupport)
>      at System.ServiceModel.Security.SspiNegotiationTokenProvider.GetOutgoingBlobProxy.GetOutgoingBlob(ChannelBinding channelBinding)
>      at System.ServiceModel.Security.RequestSecurityToken.GetBinaryNegotiation()
>      at System.ServiceModel.Security.WSTrust.Driver.WriteRequestSecurityToken(RequestSecurityToken rst, XmlWriter xmlWriter)
>      at System.ServiceModel.Security.RequestSecurityToken.WriteTo(XmlWriter writer)
>      at System.ServiceModel.Channels.BodyWriter.WriteBodyContents(XmlDictionaryWriter writer)
>      at System.ServiceModel.Channels.Message.OnWriteMessage(XmlDictionaryWriter writer)
>      at System.ServiceModel.Channels.BufferedMessageWriter.WriteMessage(Message message, BufferManager bufferManager, Int32 initialOffset, Int32 maxSizeQuota)
>      at System.ServiceModel.Channels.TextMessageEncoderFactory.TextMessageEncoder.WriteMessage(Message message, Int32 maxMessageSize, BufferManager bufferManager, Int32 messageOffset)
>      at System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpOutput.SerializeBufferedMessage(Message message)
>      at System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpOutput.Send(TimeSpan timeout)
>      at System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpChannelFactory.HttpRequestChannel.HttpChannelRequest.SendRequest(Message message, TimeSpan timeout)
>      at System.ServiceModel.Channels.RequestChannel.Request(Message message, TimeSpan timeout)
>      at System.ServiceModel.Security.IssuanceTokenProviderBase`1.DoNegotiation(TimeSpan timeout)

Stack Trace:

```
   at System.ServiceModel.Security.IssuanceTokenProviderBase`1.DoNegotiation(TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Security.SspiNegotiationTokenProvider.OnOpen(TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Security.WrapperSecurityCommunicationObject.OnOpen(TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.CommunicationObject.Open(TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Security.SecurityUtils.OpenCommunicationObject(ICommunicationObject obj, TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Security.SymmetricSecurityProtocol.OnOpen(TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Security.WrapperSecurityCommunicationObject.OnOpen(TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.CommunicationObject.Open(TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.SecurityChannelFactory`1.ClientSecurityChannel`1.OnOpen(TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.CommunicationObject.Open(TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Security.SecuritySessionSecurityTokenProvider.DoOperation(SecuritySessionOperation operation, EndpointAddress target, Uri via, SecurityToken currentToken, TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Security.SecuritySessionSecurityTokenProvider.GetTokenCore(TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.IdentityModel.Selectors.SecurityTokenProvider.GetToken(TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Security.SecuritySessionClientSettings`1.ClientSecuritySessionChannel.OnOpen(TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.CommunicationObject.Open(TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.OnOpen(TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.CommunicationObject.Open(TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.CallOnceManager.CallOnce(TimeSpan timeout, CallOnceManager cascade)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.EnsureOpened(TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.Call(String action, Boolean oneway, ProxyOperationRuntime operation, Object[] ins, Object[] outs, TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.InvokeService(IMethodCallMessage methodCall, ProxyOperationRuntime operation)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.Invoke(IMessage message)

Exception rethrown at [0]: 
   at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.HandleReturnMessage(IMessage reqMsg, IMessage retMsg)
   at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.PrivateInvoke(MessageData& msgData, Int32 type)
   at IService.GetLoginDetails(String strUserName, String strPassword)
   at ExportReportsandPointsDetails.frmLogin.btnSubmit_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e)
```

Source:

This is My config settings of WCF service:

```
public void CreateConnection()
{
    try
    {
        string strNewURL = "http://example.com/DashBoardPointsService/Service.svc";
        EndpointAddress ep = new EndpointAddress(strNewURL);                

        WSHttpBinding binding = new WSHttpBinding();
        binding.Security.Mode = SecurityMode.Message;

        binding.MaxBufferPoolSize = 819222;
        binding.MaxReceivedMessageSize = 819222;
        binding.ReceiveTimeout = TimeSpan.MaxValue;
        binding.SendTimeout = TimeSpan.MaxValue;
        binding.OpenTimeout = TimeSpan.MaxValue;
        binding.CloseTimeout = TimeSpan.MaxValue;
        binding.MaxReceivedMessageSize = 99999999;
        binding.MaxBufferPoolSize = 99999999;
        binding.ReaderQuotas.MaxArrayLength = 714748;
        binding.ReaderQuotas.MaxBytesPerRead = 214748;
        binding.ReaderQuotas.MaxDepth = 2147483647;
        binding.ReaderQuotas.MaxNameTableCharCount = 214749;
        binding.ReaderQuotas.MaxStringContentLength = 214749;

        objConnectionManager = new ChannelFactory<IService>(binding, ep);                
        objActivatedConnectionManager = objConnectionManager.CreateChannel();                

    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        objlog.Write(ex);
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you post the config of the WCF service? What is the clientCredential type? Is the machine to which the client failed to connect to, in a different domain?

Comment: This is my config of wcf and i used it in a function.

Comment: I don't see it. Did you miss formatting it? If you are trying to use wsHttpBinding and if the WCF service or client is on a different domain, it will not work. Use basicHttpBinding instead

Answer (score 0):

This is probably a rights issue.

The client has a security context that is being blocked by the server.

Check the identity of the client and the permissions on the server.